# Vuejs PWA input type file not showing dropdown options

Tags: javascript, html, ios, vue.js, progressive-web-apps

I’ve developed Vuejs PWA. The app allows users to upload images from their phones. It usually works fine. The user is able to select from the options - take a photo or upload from the camera roll. When the user downloads the app to the homescreen the image upload sometimes didn't ask to select from those options but the camera directly opens. This happens both on IOS and Android. Is there a way to force the input field to always show dropdown options? Below is the code that I am using for the input file.

`<input type="file" multiple accept="image/png,image/jpeg,image/JPEG,image/jpg"/>`

I want this dropdown to open when I click on the input file.

[image]

Comment: Odd, I don't get a dropdown in Android - I get a whole page with my images and an option to take a photo with my camera - every time - I take it the screenshot is IOS?

Comment: Yes I took this screenshot from IOS on Android it shows different screen usually I face this issue on IOS

Comment: Usually ... so only?

Comment: This dropdown only show in IOS so I face this issue on IOS

Answer (score 3):

```html
<input type="file" multiple accept="image/*"/>
```

Try this, I have used in my PWA app its never make issue and accept all formats.